# Is there a good command to replace a referenced column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

Let's say I'm working on the database using mysql to manage the user information for our customer like this.

[image: user table I'm working on]

And, there is another table that I have which references this user table with using the foreign key like the second image file.

[image: table that references user table]

Since the users in user table are referenced to the second table, I can't delete the row or change the id of users.
What I want to do is that there are tones of data in my database and I'd like to replace specific user's id with another user id.
The third image is the detail for the second table.
[image: user referencing detail]
As you see, it contains the user_id which is the id of user table. So, this blocks deleting the user information in user table.
In here, what is want is for example, I want to remove all the information of user 7 in user information and replace all the references of user 7 to user 17.
So, the user 7's info will be deleted in user table, but the rows in second table that references user 7 will be referencing user 17.
I know that we can do it manually, but since there are more than 30,000 of user data and it is almost waste of time to change it by hand.
Is there a good command that delete the user information and replace the references simultaneously?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
UPDATE verify_email SET user_id=17 WHERE user_id=7;
DELETE FROM user WHERE id=7;
```

I haven't tested it but it should work for all I know.  By doing it in this order, all references to `id=7` in table `verify_email` will be diverted to `id=17` and this should enable you to delete the `user` record with `id=7`.

Comment: Yeah, I know that works. But the problem is, there are like more than 30,000 of user id to change and if I keep update that manually, it would take more than a week. Also, there could be a mistake so I was looking for more efficient command that could do for the multiple ones.

Comment: Is there some pattern you can apply to automate the above query? I. e. is there a translation table from old to new user ids? In that case things would be easy again!